# configure nginx with 2 locations while 1 answers to specific url request

Tags: nginx, configuration

I appologize for the weird title :)

### what I have

I have two web applications running on the same server (an OSClass installation and the Vanilla Forum). One of them is supposed to be the **master** of everything (OSClass)– almost every request should be handled by that application. The other application should only answer to some specific requests (the Vanilla-Forum.. but lets call it **slave**).

**masterPage** (OSClass)
 is in directory /var/www/webroot/master 
 and listens to every request like mypage.example.com/*
 (but *not* the url to the slave page)

**slavePage** (Vanilla Forum)
 is in directory /var/www/webroot/slave/ 
 and should only listen to requests like mypage.example.com/slave/*

### how master works

the master application is working with a configuration like this one:

```
#
# some general stuff...
#

http {
    # other stuff

    server {
        listen         80;
        server_name    mypage.example.com;
        root           /var/www/webroot/master
        index          index.php
        try_files      $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        location ~ .php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/webroot/master
            fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

        # some more stuff
    }    
}
```

### how I try to get slave to work

I thought, since the configuration works for master why not duplicate the 'server' environment and adjust it to slave. something like this:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    mypage.example.com/slave;
    root           /var/www/webroot/slave
    index          index.php
    try_files      $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/webroot/slave
        fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }         
    # some more stuff  
}
```

But that does not work – the url *mypage.example.com/slave* still leads to the **master** page.. I also tried two location definitions, but apparently I can't define a location for **master**, that works for every request except the ones that should be handled by **slave**.. e.g.

```
location /(!/slave)
```

sorry, I really don't understand much about server configurations and until now I haven't found any tutorial that helps me here. Does anyone know how I could configure the server? Or is there a *regex* I could use to exclude the **slave** from the **master**-location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`server_name` is the domain name of the server, it cannot contain any other parts of the URL.

You can do what you want with the following setup:

```
#
# some general stuff...
#

http {
    # other stuff

    server {
        listen         80;
        server_name    mypage.example.com;
        root           /var/www/webroot/master
        index          index.php
        try_files      $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location /slave {
            alias /var/www/webroot/slave;
        }

        location ~ .php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

        # some more stuff
    }    
}
```

The `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` should already be defined in nginx common configuration (fastcgi_params), so there is no need to include it here. Actually it was configured wrong here.

The `alias` directive sets the directory where files for this URI location are served from.

Comment: wow, thanks!! setting an `alias`.. who would have guessed :) It's the first time I saw the `Vanilla` (the slave) page on this server! But apparently I still need the `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME..` line. I put it into the *slave* location, pointing to `webroot`. But I still needed a `/`-location (with the fastcgi_param pointing to the *master* directory)...otherwise the *master* would deny me access (because it was thinking I wanted to access the file-system). Anyways, thank you very much! – I am not sure I understand everything... but its working, and thats a start :)